# Upgrade Version of Apt manually?

Tags: apt

I'm in a situation where I want to use a feature introduced to `apt` in version 1.1. I'm on an older version of Ubuntu 14.04 on an ARM device.

Even when I use `apt-get upgrade` I can't get the latest version of apt.

Would it be safe to upgrade the apt program manually? If so how would I go about doing it?

Comment: is it available in your repository? `apt-get install apt` should do it

Comment: @ravery no the latest version in my repository is less than 1.1

Comment: Which feature is it?

Comment: Why not install a newer Ubuntu release?

Comment: @muru we're running `apt-get install --force-yes`. We'd rather be using `apt-get install --allow-downgrades`. This relates to the automation of upgrading and changing package versions.

Comment: @Pilot6 because our product has been developed on Ubuntu 14.04, upgrading to 16.04 would require testing and updating several different scripts and programs.

Comment: It is very unlikely that you can install the new apt to 14.04 easily. And it also may require testing and upgrading some other packages. You can try a package from another distro, or build `apt `from source.

Answer (score -1):

The safest way is to see if it has been backported
enable the backport repositories.

Next option is to download it from the repository that has it.
Provided it doesn't create a dependency mess it should run fine.

though, updated software often requires updated dependencies

Comment: "Backport repository" is not related at all. What is the repository "that has it"? The answer is not useful because it is like: "you can find it somewhere".

Comment: a quick search says 15.10 hasit, but he is using ARM may be different for his

Comment: Yes, lots of releases have 1.1+ versions of apt. But they are hardly installable to 14.04.

Comment: that's why I said to to check dependencies .....

Comment: It is not a good answer anyway. How OP is supposed to "check dependencies"? Theoretically you could write a good answer on how to try to install software from other releases. But I suspect I saw a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: the package tells you. and you could temporarily point your repo to the appropriate versioin. but you would probably complain about that answer also